# How to submit a query with the keyboard in eXist-db?

Tags: keyboard, submit, shortcut, exist-db

While working with eXist, once I have written the query, I have to grab the mouse, point the Submit button and click it. I think this is a great lost of time if you have to do it thousands of times. Moreover I'm very used to do it with the keyboard in other programms I use.
Does anybody how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Which eXist client are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using eXist-db's web-based code editor, eXide, you can submit queries using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac).  It works quite well.

Comment: Thanks, @vanda!  I'll keep the `<kbd>` in mind for next time.